# Anguler2 - Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ViewContainerRef! ( In dynamic template )

Tags: angular

I am trying to implement dynamic component. 
My requirement is, I have three class- LayoutComponent, MenuService and DynamicService. 
LayoutComponent is used to call the MenuService's method to perform some basic operation, after performing operation, MenuService's method again call to DynamicService's method for creating dynamic component.

Here is my [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/vZmwHuIV3uCbrZ2pMMYw) with the following error which it gives

`Unhandled Promise rejection: No provider for ViewContainerRef! ;`

Comment: Why are you naming services `XxxComponent`? (like `MenuComponent` or  `DynamicComponent`?

Comment: a clear rookie mistake..have corrected

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`ViewContainerRef` can only be injected to components or directives, but not to services.

Components and directives get the `ViewContainerRef` of the element where they itself are attached. A service isn't attached to any view.

What you can do is to inject `ViewContainerRef` **and** a service to a component and then in the constructor pass the `ViewContainerRef` to the service. Every service or component that injects this service can access the `ViewContainerRef` it holds.

Comment: doing the same in the code, injecting the 'ViewContainerRef ' and passing it in the constructor to the services to access..or am i injecting it wrongly?

Comment: can you guide me how to inject the 'ViewContainerRef ' in the component properly.

Comment: `constructor(viewContainerRef:ViewContainerRef, service:MyService){ service.vcRef = viewContainerRef; }`

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear you could make it work.

Comment: This saves my day. Thanks.

Comment: Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was using `ng2-toastr` and it caused the problem.

Calling `setRootViewContainerRef()` of `toastr` will solve your problem.

```
constructor(dialogService: DialogService,
        private toastr: ToastsManager,
        private vcr: ViewContainerRef) {
        super(dialogService);
        this.toastr.setRootViewContainerRef(vcr);
    }
```